# Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function. Prove f is injective if and only if each $\sim$ equivalence class has a unique element, where $\sim$ is $f(a)=f(b)$.

Tags: equivalence-relations

Here is my proof so far:

(=>) Let $f: X \to Y$. If $f$ is injective, then $f(a) = f(b)$ implies $a = b$. So for $f(a) = f(b), a = b$. thus for the equivalence class $[a]$, $[a] = \lbrace b \in X \mid f(b) = f(a)\rbrace$. since $b = a$, $a$ is the unique element in $[a]$.

(<=) Let each $\sim$ equivalence class have a unique element. Let $a$ be in $[a]$ be a unique element. Then $[a] = \lbrace x \in X \mid f(x) = f(a)\rbrace$. So for each unique element $a$, $f(x) = f(a)$. Since $a$ is a unique element in $a$, then $x = a$.

I'm stuck on the second part of the proof (<=). I don't think what I currently have for to get from f(x) = f(a) implies x = a makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The proof is fine for me.

Comment: Agreed. Why do you think its incomplete? (Even if rough idea of what you think is missing could be helpful).

Comment: I think my second part of the proof (<=) does not really make sense. I'm not 100% sure how to get from f(x) = f(a) implies x = a.

Comment: Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$. Then $a \sim b$, so $b \in [a]$, and of course $a \in [a]$. But if $[a]$ has only one element, then it must be that $b = a$